# SQL difference between IN and OR in WHERE

Tags: sql

What is the difference between the following two commands?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = id1 OR id = id2 OR ... OR id = idn
```

Which one is faster? And will it be different if `id` is another type?

Comment: It would also be good to know what SQL implementation we are talking about here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**They are semantically identical.**

`IN` is just a shorthand for a string of equality statements like in your second example.  Performance should also be identical.

The type shouldn't matter, it will always evaluate to a string of equalities.

There is a difference when you are using `NOT IN` and data that can be `NULL`, though - a `NULL` will not evaluate false for a `NOT IN` comparison, so you may get rows you didn't expect in the result set.

As an example:

`SELECT 'Passed!' WHERE NULL NOT IN ('foo', 'bar')`

The above query will not return a row even though at face value `NULL` is neither `'foo'` or `'bar'` - this is because `NULL` is an unknown state, and SQL cannot say with certainty that the unknown value is **NOT** one of the `IN` listed values.

Comment: `There is a difference when you are using NOT IN` -- how so? `NOT IN` === `f != 1 AND f != 2`. And both expressions again are optimized in the same (terrible) way

Comment: @zerkms - not with `NULL`, at least in SQL Server. `SELECT 1
WHERE NULL NOT IN ('foo', 'bar')` - you won't get a row, but you would expect to since `NULL` isn't either foo or bar

Comment: ah, I though you mean that there are 2 different cases: when you use `NOT IN` and when there is a `NULL` inside the parentheses

Comment: @zerkms - no, when you are comparing `NULL` to a `NOT IN` - it won't evaluate true since SQL can't say for sure that the `NULL` is definitely NOT one of those values

Comment: hehe I know that, I just said it wasn't obvious (for me) from your post - that you said what you said ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - fair enough, added an example to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on specific DBMS optimizer implementation and engine itself.

But you should be just fine with thinking that they are semantically similar and being optimized in a similar way.

The optimization wouldn't depend on the field type

Answer (score 1):

at least in sqlserver both gives same execution plan !!!

Comment: I think the question is asking in terms of tuning, not operation.

Comment: @Brian is my anwser incomplete? in any terms the querys are equal, except in readability witch is obvious diferent

Comment: @Brian L.: "Which one is faster?" --- this is clear question and this answer, to be clear, partially answers it (even though I don't like it ;-) +1 anyway

Comment: @zerkms, thanks. sometimes is hard for non-english speaking guys

Answer (score 0):

Every DBMS reliable enough preforms IN operator much better because of the data structure.
Moreover, when the db calculates a sql plan, it does not necessarily translates  the OR form into the IN form, just because OR operator could combine different conditions altogether.
From logical perspective they are quite the same.

Answer (score -3):

I think IN is faster purely because you give an easier query that the server can handle.
Just my thought.

See the following comment by Fernando Giovanini in this article, he mentions that IN makes it not only more readable but also faster: http://www.ajaxline.com/32-tips-to-speed-up-your-mysql-queries#comment-325677194

Comment: It is not possible to say anything is faster than anything else when you use `secmatrix like '%8:0%' OR  secmatrix LIKE '%8:0%' OR  secmatrix LIKE '%4:0%' OR  secmatrix LIKE '%2:0%'` in your query. It looks at least funny (or stuid) ;-)

Comment: personally I'd advice you never to refer to unknown people with statements without any proofs (especially when it is completely wrong)

Comment: I never stated that what he said was true, nor did I say that what I said was true. All I did was give my thoughts and refer to an article. That's why multiple people place answers, everyone has their own opinion and/or experience. See the overview and you'll know which side is winning.

Comment: programming is not a science about random thoughts. There is an answer for the question and it has nothing to do with random guesses. "I never stated that what he said was true" --- any reason to answer if you're not sure you're correct and sure even a guy you're referring to correct??

Comment: Well of course there is an answer for the question, I didn't have it but I did have something to say about the subject. That's not a crime I believe? Luckily there were people that knew better answers, if I'd seen that I wouldn't have said anything. All I did was in case he wasn't going to get an answer from anyone he'd have someone's thought on the subject.

Comment: "in case he wasn't going to get an answer from anyone he'd have someone's thought on the subject" --- wrong thoughts worse than no thoughts at all. There are zillion of terrible mentions and articles in the internet, and there is no reason to refer to them just because no one else answered.

Comment: Ahem, I'm sorry sir but I think you're just trying to bash me on the fact that my answer was wrong. How would I know that my thought and source was wrong? We'd only find that out when other people do post the right answer, which happened. No need to make a fuzz out of it.

Comment: "How would I know that my thought and source was wrong" --- there is a great rule - you're not sure in something - then assume you're wrong. There is no proofs of some mention/assertion - suppose it is wrong too. That's simple, isn't it? ;-) "No need to make a fuzz out of it" --- I'm just trying to say that referring to some strange thoughts makes SO worse, as long as it becomes the non-argumentative and non-trust source of information for developers

Comment: I'm ending this discussion as I can see this is taking us nowhere :P we're not going to agree on anything so let's just get along :)