# is there any difference between the queries

Tags: sql, select, database-performance

1. `select field from table where field = 'value'`
2. `select field from table where field in ('value')`

The reason I'm asking is that the second version allow me to use the same syntax for null values, while in the first version I need to change the condition to 'where field is null'...

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: What happens when you do `in ('value', null)`? do you get rows where `field` is `null` ?

Comment: when you are comparing null values to a field without using `IN` you need to use `IS NULL`

Comment: Your question is similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL difference between IN and OR in WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024594/sql-difference-between-in-and-or-in-where)

Comment: By the way what exactly RDBMS did you use? MySQL, MS SQL, PostGre? Because using IN clause does not return anything when NULL is used. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d72573/6) and [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7257/2).

Comment: @Edper: the database is called Postgres or PostgreSQL. Never PostGre (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I realize that the moment I post it but did not mind to change it. You're correct by the way. Thanks.

Comment: I though I can use `in ('value', null)` but it seems not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are comparing a field to a null like `field_name=NULL` you are comparing to a known data type from a field say `varchar` to not only an unknown value but also an unknown data type as well, that is, for `NULL` values. When comparison like `field_name=NULL` again implies therefore a checking of data type for both and thus the two could not be compared even if the value of the field is actually `NULL` thus it will always result to `false`. However, using the `IS NULL` you are only comparing for the value itself without the implied comparison for data type thus it could result either to `false` or `true` depending on the actual value of the field.

See reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) regarding the issue of `NULL` in computer science and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null) in relation to the similarity to your question.

Now, for the IN clause (i.e. `IN(NULL)`) I don't know what RDBMS you are using because when I tried it with MS SQL and MySQL it results to nothing.

See [MS SQL example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11b3b/1) and [MySQL example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11b3b/1).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in your example.  The second, slightly longer, query is not usually used for a single value, it is usally seen for multiple values, such as

```
select field from table where field in ('value1', 'value2')
```

Comment: Mark: I think the OP was not basically asking the difference between the regular `WHERE` and one using `IN` statement. The OP was asking why `field_here=null` is different than `IS NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

yes there is difference in both this queries. In first statment you can insert only 1 value in where clause "where field = 'value'" but in second statement in where field you can insert many values using IN clause "where field in (value1,value2..)"
Examples:

```
1) select field from table where field ='value1';

2) select field from table where field in ('value1', 'value2')
```

To check null values

```
SELECT field
FROM tbl_name
WHERE 
(field IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') OR field IS NULL)
```

Comment: This not the expected answer, we need to know the difference in execution plan, say if i use = operator what is the difference and if i use IN clause what is the difference.

Comment: @Murtaza Can you please check i have corrected answer now..And if it is not so u can update my answer.