# what is actual difference between or operator and in operator in sql

Tags: sql

When I am using `OR` operator it shows those values which are used in `OR` operater after where clause `IN` also do the same.

Please let me know the difference between both.

Comment: Share the query and show us the expected result.

Comment: it is the same relation as between the (propositional) *logical "or"* and the (predicate) *logical "exists"* operator...

Comment: ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification ! ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `IN` operator can be rewritten into a series of `OR` conditions:

```
where some_column IN (1,2,3)
```

is equivalent to

```
where some_column = 1 
   or some_column = 2 
   or some_column = 3
```

In terms of functionality they are 100% identical. As far as performance is concerned they usually are the same as well - but this depends a lot on the concrete DBMS product being used and several other factors.

---

A series of conditions combined with `OR` can only be rewritten into an `IN` if they all work on the same column (and thus use the same data type), so fhe following can **NOT** be rewritten into an `IN` operator

```
where col_1 = 1 
   or col_2 = current_date
   or col_3 = 'some value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are identical.
OR is made for comaprison of less values as well as comparison of different columns whearas IN is for range of values for same column.
You can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024594/sql-difference-between-in-and-or-in-where) for more

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `or` operator has two operands unless I am missing something.

Comment: @SalmanA: a if that's what you mean ;) - I was thinking about combining multiple OR conditions for multiple values. But indeed, a single OR only compares two values

Comment: Also, `IN` is easier to combine with additional conditions. E.g. `where c1 in (1,2) and c2 = 3` <> `where c1 = 1 or c1 = 2 and c2 = 3`.